# Define a makefile target from variables set with eval

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have to define a target that contains a version number, which in turn is extracted from some file (the prerequisite of this target) retrieved from git.

What I first tried was to set a variable with `eval` and use this in the name, like this.

```
version_file:
  @checkout

version: version_file
  @eval version := get version from version_file

file_$(version):
  @echo file_$(version)

final_target: file_$(version)
  @echo $@
```

This cannot work: `make` reads the makefile in the first pass and does not find the variable `dynamic_prerequisite`, so the target created is simply named `file_`.

But when I try to create the rule dynamically, after the variable has been set, like this

```
...
define rule_file_version
file_$(version):
  @echo version: $@
endef

version: version_file
  @eval version := get version from version_file
  $(eval $(rule_file_version))
```

... this gives me the error message:

> makefile:12: *** prerequisites cannot be defined in recipes.

Of course I cannot move the `eval` for the target outside of the recipe, as I then encounter the same problem as before.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with `gnu make`?

Comment: You seem to want to compute the value of `dynamic_prerequisite` in a black box. Do you have a preference about whether the black box is a script or a rule?

Comment: It is a script in my use case.

Comment: Now, that I see your answer I recognize that my example is actually overly simplified. Also my answer should have been "rule", because the script itself depends on another target. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem can be solved by using [constructed include files](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/#more-143).

For the construction of the files itself I created a simple shell script, that takes the dynamically set variable as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' MAKE <<EOF
file_$1:
    @echo version: $1

final_target: file_$1
    @echo final_target: $1
EOF

echo "$MAKE" > rules.mk
```

This is used in the `makefile` to create an included makefile `rules.mk`, like this:

```
version_file:
  @checkout

version: version_file
  @eval version := get version from version_file

rules.mk: version
    $(shell ./create_rules_mk.sh $(version))

-include rules.mk
```

When I run `make final_target` it creates the `rules.mk` as wished.

The bottom line for me is, that target names, that themselves depend on other targets have to use dynamic creation of makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler approach:

blackbox.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1.0
```

Makefile:

```
dynamic_prerequisite := $(shell ./blackbox.sh)

file_$(dynamic_prerequisite):
    @echo target is $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a build tool more suited to dynamic targets.  For example, I've written a Gnu Make-like tool incorporating some of the concepts from DJB's ReDo, called [GoodMake](https://github.com/AmesCornish/GoodMake).  Your equivalent makefile would just be:

```
#? version_file
    checkout

#? final_target
    $0 version_file     # Static dependency
    version=$(get version from version_file)
    $0 file_$version    # Dynamic dependency
```

Simpler, huh?  If you try out GoodMake, I'd love to hear what you think!